# PHP library for Generating random IDs and avoid collisions like Nodejs hat module

Tags: php, node.js

Is there any library available to generate random IDs in PHP.
In Nodejs we have `hat` module to generate random IDs

Node js.

```
var hat = require('hat');
var rack = hat.rack();

console.log(rack());
console.log(rack());
```

any PHP library?

Answer (score 1):

> Use [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) which Generate a unique ID

Try this:

```html
<?php
echo uniqid().'<br>';
echo uniqid().'<br>';
echo uniqid().'<br>';
echo uniqid().'<br>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Exception\UnsatisfiedDependencyException;

try {

    // Generate a version 1 (time-based) UUID object
    $uuid1 = Uuid::uuid1();
    echo $uuid1->toString() . "\n"; // i.e. e4eaaaf2-d142-11e1-b3e4-080027620cdd

    // Generate a version 3 (name-based and hashed with MD5) UUID object
    $uuid3 = Uuid::uuid3(Uuid::NAMESPACE_DNS, 'php.net');
    echo $uuid3->toString() . "\n"; // i.e. 11a38b9a-b3da-360f-9353-a5a725514269

    // Generate a version 4 (random) UUID object
    $uuid4 = Uuid::uuid4();
    echo $uuid4->toString() . "\n"; // i.e. 25769c6c-d34d-4bfe-ba98-e0ee856f3e7a

    // Generate a version 5 (name-based and hashed with SHA1) UUID object
    $uuid5 = Uuid::uuid5(Uuid::NAMESPACE_DNS, 'php.net');
    echo $uuid5->toString() . "\n"; // i.e. c4a760a8-dbcf-5254-a0d9-6a4474bd1b62

} catch (UnsatisfiedDependencyException $e) {

    // Some dependency was not met. Either the method cannot be called on a
    // 32-bit system, or it can, but it relies on Moontoast\Math to be present.
    echo 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php

Note that by randomly generating ID's there is always a chance of collision (even though it's nearly equal to 0).

You should be good with GUIDS.

Answer (score 0):

Try [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). It generates unique identifier based on microtime() and works both on unix and windows.